# How to update couchbase lite view with Rest API?

Tags: couchbase-lite

How to update couchbase lite view  with Rest API ?

From Rest API how to tell indexer that view is updated . I have tried the below code but it did not work.It still returns the old index.

What is the correct way of telling indexer that view is updated so that it can recreate the index.

```
    'PUT'
    {db}/_design/todo
            {
"_rev":"hf675757577hhfh",
        "views":{
    "list":{
    "map":function(doc){
    if(doc.type=='list')
    {
    emit(doc._id,{"name":doc.name});
    }
    },
    //"version":"1.0" (I have tryied this but not work)
    }

    }

            }

//My view create request was like below:


  {db}/_design/todo
            {

        "views":{
    "list":{
    "map":function(doc){
    if(doc.type=='list')
    {
    emit(doc._id,{"name":doc.name});
    }
    },
    //"version":"1.0" (I have tryied this but not work)
    }

    }

            }
```

Comment: Is this a view that you created via the REST API?  If not you cannot update it via the rest API.

Comment: yaa i have created  view list before

Comment: How did you create it?  Via an initial PUT request?  If there is a natively registered view there then this will not change it.  Otherwise, if there is no native view at all, each PUT should cause the view to reindex since the version is based on a hash of the source.  What platform is this running on?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you may just have some formatting problems.  This shows how to do what you're trying from the command line:

```
curl -X PUT 'http://localhost:4985/db/_design/todo' --header 'Content-Type: application/json' --header 'Accept: application/json' -d '{ "_rev": "hf675757577hhfh", "views": { "list": { "map": "function(doc) { if (doc.type == \"list\") { emit(doc._id, { \"name\": doc.name }); }}"}}}'
```

You can test your results with this command:

```
curl -X GET 'http://localhost:4985/db/_design/todo/_view/list'
```

You may want to refer to the documentation, which has more examples, at https://developer.couchbase.com/documentation/mobile/current/guides/sync-gateway/views/index.html